# Why does Eclipse 3.5.1 narrow to the declaration when I go to the declaration of a field?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-3.5.1

I just installed 64-bit Eclipse 3.5.1 on SnowLeopard. I am experiencing a rather strange problem, and I'm posting a question here to see if anyone can explain or confirm it before I go get tangled up with the Eclipse bugzilla.

I open up a Java class with some errors in it. I double-click on a reference to a field. I click right and select 'open declaration'.

The windows then shows me ONLY the declaration. I smell a feature here, but I can't figure out how to get Eclipse to go back to displaying the entire class except by closing and reopening the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into the Eclipse Preferences and under Java > Editor you will see a checkbox for "Only show the selected Java element"... what you describe sounds like the behavior when that is checked. Try unchecking it.

Good luck.